# ios UIAlertView: make alert wait for my response

Tags: ios, ipad, uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make UIAlertView blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753154/make-uialertview-blocking)

Been beating my head against the wall for hours on this one.

Here's what I've got:  OrderDetailsViewController is set as an UIAlertViewDelegate

I've got a procedure that receives information back from a search form.  It checks to see if the item is already on the order and if not continues adding the item(s).  If it sees a duplicate, it pops up a UIAlertView asking what the user wants to do: there are 3 options, "Combine" - add the new qty to the old item, "Add" the duplicate as a separate line item, or "Cancel" throw the new item away.  I need it to wait for an answer from the UIAlertView  so that I can continue adding the dupe or throwing away the dupe -- the "Combine" is handled in the delegate, but I still need an answer for the main procedure.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 - (void)returnItemAndQty:(ProductsSearchController *)productsSearchController
         withItemsToAdd:(NSMutableArray *)itemsToAdd 
         withQty:(NSDictionary *)qtyToAdd andClose:(BOOL)close
{
if ([itemsToAdd count] == 0) {
    return;
}
Items *items;
for (int index = 0; index < [itemsToAdd count]; index++) {
    items = [itemsToAdd objectAtIndex:index];
    qtyAddedToOrder = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[qtyToAdd objectForKey:items.ItemCode]];     
    NSLog(@"Item Code: %@", items.ItemCode);
    NSLog(@"Qty: %@", [qtyToAdd objectForKey:items.ItemCode]);
    NSError *error;

    //For handling duplicate items. . . 
    duplicateItemDisposition = -1; //Reset the dispostion for normal operation
    if([self isItemOnOrder:items.ItemCode])
    {
        int i = [self itemIsAlreadyOnOrder:itemAlreadyOnOrder withQty:qtyAddedToOrder];

        if (i == COMBINE || i == CANCEL){ //either Cancel or Combine was pressed.
            items.Checked = NO;
            if (![items.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    //Add the new item or duplicate if that's what you want
    OrdersDetails *newOrderDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OrdersDetails" 
                                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

.//more code snipped, that handles the "ADD" or non-dupe
.
.
```

Here's where it tests for a duplicate. . .

```
- (BOOL)isItemOnOrder:(NSString *)itemCode
{

 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OrdersDetails"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"Desc1" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sort, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sort release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ItemCode=%@ AND OrderID=%@)", itemCode, orders.OrderID];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:& error] mutableCopy];
   [request release];
   if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
       itemAlreadyOnOrder = nil;
       return NO;
   }else if ([mutableFetchResults count] > 0){
       itemAlreadyOnOrder = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
       return YES;
   }else{
       itemAlreadyOnOrder = nil;
       return NO;
   }
}
```

Here's where it sees that a dupe exists and the UIAlertview delegate with it. . .

```
- (int) itemIsAlreadyOnOrder:(OrdersDetails *)existingOrderDetail withQty:(NSDecimalNumber *)qty 
{
    if (existingOrderDetail == nil) {
    return -1;
    }

    UIAlertView *duplicateAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duplicate Item %@ found.",existingOrderDetail.ItemCode] message:@"Tap Combine to combine the items, Tap Add to add the duplicate item or Tap Cancel to discard the duplicate" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Combine", @"Add", nil];
    [duplicateAlert show];

    return duplicateItemDisposition;

    [duplicateAlert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
// Cancel = 0, Combine = 1, Add = 2

    if (buttonIndex == CANCEL){
        duplicateItemDisposition = CANCEL;
    }else if (buttonIndex == COMBINE){
            duplicateItemDisposition = COMBINE;
            NSDecimalNumber *existingQty = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[itemAlreadyOnOrder.Qty decimalValue]];
            NSDecimalNumber *existingPrice = itemAlreadyOnOrder.Price;
            NSDecimalNumber *newQty = [existingQty decimalNumberByAdding:qtyAddedToOrder];
            itemAlreadyOnOrder.ExtPrice = [newQty decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:existingPrice];
           [existingQty release];
           NSError *error;
           if (![itemAlreadyOnOrder.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error saving. %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
               [self handleFreeGoods:itemAlreadyOnOrder];
           }else if (buttonIndex == ADD){
               duplicateItemDisposition = ADD;
           }
}
```

Now I read something on here about using an NSCondition in a background thread, but I have no idea what that means.  I looked up NSCondition, and it was less than enlightening.

Any ideas on how to pause the execution?

Comment: Are you performing some work on an NSOperation or some other method of background execution? What is it you're trying to 'pause'?

Comment: I am not.  I am basically just trying to get the code to wait for a response from UIAlertView before continuing on.  I am not using any background execution or multi-threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIAlertView` can't block, as it gets displayed at the end of the runloop. Instead of having the method `itemIsAlreadyOnOrder:` return a value indicating what should be done with the duplicate entry, the delegate method from the `UIAlertView` needs to notify your controller that the item in question has been resolved. Track the object in question somewhere (`_objectToVerify` or something like that), and in the delegate method from the `UIAlertView` call a method based on the users choice, which will act on that `_objectToVerify`.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I'm not sure I understand.  Since I'm checking for the duplicate in the method that adds items, I'm not sure how I would handle a non-duplicate.

Comment: I think you are expecting the UIAlertView -show method to block execution - it won't, and can't. Other than implementing your own popup view (which isn't that terribly difficult, but it's nonstandard), the only choice is to change how your code works so that it doesn't do anything until the UIAlertView calls `clickedButtonAtIndex`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure how to do that.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Change you `itemIsAlreadyOnOrder` method so it (and it's callers) do nothing after it returns. Move any logic which followed it into the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method. Basically, instead of making your application logic a series of steps (check if it's a dupe, display alert, do something, do something else), have events which cause your application to react (if it's a dupe display alert, then the alert causes the next step to occur).

Comment: I get that if it's a dupe, I should handle it in the delegate.  But if it's not a dupe, I've still got things to do, so how would I trigger the rest of the stuff that's got to be done? not to mention the other items that are returned in the array?  I'm just not sure how to structure it so that it handles it all.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'll just do another viewcontroller and present it modally.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, did some rearranging and think i've got it nailed.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Oh and in case it might help somebody else: what I'm doing is adding the duplicate line items to an array and dealing with them after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this might change your current design, but the Cocoa design pattern would have the method that puts up the alert not return anything, so something like `if (duplicate) showAlertView` in pseudocode. Then in the alert view's delegate, call a method that actually handles the processing of the duplicate based on user input.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it like that the first time.  Like I said I've been around and around with this.  I can't really handle all of the duplicate cases because one of them is to just let it go.  Also the last part of the code handles non-duplicates, so the alert never even gets thrown.

Comment: Have you considered a UIActionSheet?

Comment: I hadn't considered UIActionSheet.  I'll look into it.

Comment: Same problem with UIActionSheet