# UIAlertView Not showing immediately after call of [alert show]

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

How to make appear the alert view immediately after i call [alert show] without executing the code below the call for [alert show].

Comment: Your question has been answered here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753154/make-uialertview-blocking

Comment: Thanks but i did not get concept stated in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to wait executing the code below until the user dismisses the alert view? If so, you should implement the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) protocol and handle the '– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:' method.

Comment: Yes first i want to handle the alert view delegate and then process the other code below [alert show].

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct You can use `UIAlertViewDelegate`

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView;
```

Move your code below `[alert show]` to above the delegate function.