# How to make UIAlertView pause thread and wait user response, iOS dev

Tags: ios, uialertview

Please read through all my question and see if it is duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753154/make-uialertview-blocking)

Sometimes I believe iOS is the best OS and xCode is the most elegant IDE too, but sometimes I think they're both the stupidest thing in the world and maybe the whole universe!

What I need SEEMS easy, code logic like this

```
//code BEFORE asking user's decision
//with a lot of variables, this is important

//call UIAlertView to ask user Yes/No question, now the thread should be paused and waiting for user's tap on button

//code AFTER get user tap a button, selected YES/NO
//MANY variables before asking should be continuely used here
answerIsYES = //response from UIAlertView
if (answerIsYES)
{
     //code response to YES
}else{
     //code response to NO
}
```

If you noticed "MANY variables" before and after UIAlertView show, you will not suggest me to use UIAlertViewDelegate. If that, I have to make all the variables at class-level and what if I have to ask user's decision in FOR loop? That cannot jump to SelectedButtonAtIndex method and come back! Am I right? I want to make my code integrated but the UIAlertView and its delegate seems keeping split them.

Put it simple, what I want is just a MessageBox from .NET, it can wait for user's click. So is there any code that can ahieve this on iOS? Is there a code in iOS can just simple "pause" a thread and then triggerd by some event and "resume" it??

I have searched a lot and cannot find a satisfied answer, the answers involved "NSCondition", "NSThread", "loop", but none really works well. But I did found one in the link at first, respond by @Joseph Gagliardo, I don't know if that's the best solution.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're asking for, but I'm afraid this really is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753154/make-uialertview-blocking.  The UIAlertView APIs appear to be deliberately designed to prevent the modal alert pattern.  Note that in AppKit there is NSAlert, which does include various methods for running alerts in a modal way, but Apple did not include this ability in UIKit.  I suspect it was decided that blocking alerts did not belong in iOS apps.

Comment: @AaronGolden Thanks, I guess the reason for not including modal alert in UIKit is that maybe Apple thinks iOS should be more light-weighted and less complex. Anyway, I might have to give up this logic in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIAlertView`, like most other aspects of UIKit, is event driven. You don't want the main thread blocked while an alert is being displayed. Many times other things need to keep going while the alert is in view. But there is a good solution to your issue. Blocks.

UIKit classes that have been added more recently are starting to make use of blocks. This makes writing event driven code easier. It eliminates the need for separate delegate methods just to handle the completion of some event.

Do a Google search on "UIAlertView blocks". You will find several 3rd party versions of `UIAlertView` that make use of blocks. The use of this type of alert view will allow you to keep all of your code in the one method. These solutions don't pause the main thread or anything. It just makes it much easier for the completion block to access all of the variables you have setup just prior to displaying the alert view.

Comment: Thanks, I guess adding block is the final solution, though I was trying to make it better.

Comment: There are other solutions too but using blocks is the cleanest. You can get clever with `dispatch_semaphore_xxx` functions for example.